# How to make Terminal Share work in VSCode LiveShare?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-liveshare

LiveShare works fine, but when we want to start sharing a terminal (read-only/read-write) it gives the following error message:

```
Sharing Terminal: Extension 'ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare' CANNOT use API proposal: terminalDataWriteEvent. Its package.json#enabledApiProposals-property declares: fileSearchProvider, findTextInFiles, notebookEditor, textSearchProvider but NOT terminalDataWriteEvent. The missing proposal MUST be added and you must start in extension development mode or use the following command line switch: --enable-proposed-api ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
```

Downgrading VSCode is not an option.

> VSCode version: 1.64.2
>
> LiveShare version: 1.0.5330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***TL;DR : Followed exactly what the error says.***

1. Open VSCode and press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`, then select `Preference: Configure Runtime Arguments`
2. Add the `ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare` item to the `enable-proposed-api` list. Create if it doesn't exist.

```json
{
    .
    .
    .
    "enable-proposed-api": [
        ...
        "ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare"
    ]
}
```

3. Navigate to your VSCode extensions directory.

- Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- macOS `~/.vscode/extensions`
- Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`

4. Find the correct directory for liveshare, usually it is `ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-<version>`, and open the `package.json` file inside it.
5. Add the following items to the `enabledApiProposals` list. Create if it doesn't exist.

```json
{
    .
    .
    .
    "enabledApiProposals": [
        ...
        "terminalDataWriteEvent",
        "terminalDimensions"
    ]
}
```

6. Quit and restart VSCode